# jQuery to access JSON conceptNet

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to display the json response from the server on my webpage 
but i m getting this error " XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/data/5.1/c/en/david_beckham. Origin http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

the code i wrote is

```
<i><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">

</div>
<script>
$.getJSON("http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/data/5.1/c/en/david_beckham",

  function(data) {
 $.each(data.edges, function(i,data){
                   alert(JSON.stringify(data))
                   var div_data = "<div ><a href='"+data.rel+"'>"+data.end+"</a></div>";
                   $(data).appendTo("#content");
               });

  });</script>

</body>
</html></i>
```

Plz help me to get the result on webpage

Comment: You cannot make cross-domain requests unless the servers supports `JSONP`. Sorry.

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is a header that is to be set on server, so you can make cross domain requestshttps://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/data/5.1/c/en/david_beckham',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

If it doesnt work, create a file on the serverside that generates the json for you, and call your file from your jquery ajax call.

Comment: The service doesn't return jsonp.

Comment: The best workaround is to use `cURL` and generate a JSON object based on the `cURL parameters.`

Comment: Kevin B if service doesnt return jsonp then how do we access it